# No reverse match "error during template rendering"

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

Reverse for 'all_products' not found. 'all_products' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
     <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url "store:all_products" %}">All</a></li>
     {% for c in categories %}
         <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name|title }}</a>
         </li>
     {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

here is my my def in views.py :

```
def all_products(request):
    products = Product.products.all()
    return render(request, 'store/home.html', {'products': products})
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'store'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.all_products, name = 'all products'),
    path('item/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('search/<slug:category_slug>/', views.category_list, name='category_list'),]
```

Project urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('store.urls', namespace='store')),]

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: show your urls.py

Comment: i added my urls.py

Comment: does it work without ```store:```?

Comment: no it does not wotk !! same error message

Comment: getting the same error there..? share error traceback

Comment: share project urls too..

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access `http://localhost:8000/` or `http://localhost:8000/store`?

And you should change

`path('', views.all_products, name = 'all products'),` for

`path('', views.all_products, name = 'all_products'),`

Answer (score 1):

In This line of your template 

<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url "store:all_products" %}">All

 valid name should be supplied i.e;
**{% url "namespace:name" %}** here you have used **all_products** as name but no url is defined with this name kindly change the name of first url in urls.py to:

```
path('', views.all_products, name = 'all_products'),
```